# Search result ordering by precedence in rails

Tags: postgresql, sorting, search, ruby-on-rails-4

I am searching against title and description of Products. it works cool but all i need a search like to get a result  precedence based. like in result products with title match comes first then description.
Here is my controller code:

```
def products
    scope = Product.joins(:vendor).enabled.includes(:vendor, :images)

    # Make sure to select only available vendors
    scope = scope.where("vendors.enabled = ?", true)

    # Filter by vendor
    if params[:vendor_id].present?
      scope = scope.where(vendor_id: params[:vendor_id])
    end

    if params[:search].present?
      scope = scope.filter(params[:search])
    end
    scope
  end
```

and here is model. product.rb

```
def self.filter(search)
    where("title ILIKE '%#{search}%' OR description ILIKE '%#{search}%'")
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the outcome of this will be that you have a set of `Product` objects that match the search in one of their fields.

The missing part is that now you need to sort your results- you can do this as part of your query but it's relatively hard work and I would be inclined to do the work in Ruby.

I would start by generating a result score based on the number of occurrences of the search terms in your result, something like this:

```
def score_result( result, search_term )
   score = result.title =~ search_term ? 5 : 0
   score+= result.text =~ search_term ? 1: 0
end
```

Then you could apply that as a filter on your search:

```
if params[:search].present?
  searchPattern = Regexp.new(params[:search])
  scope = scope.filter(params[:search]).sort_by { | res | score_result(res, searchPattern) }
end
```

That should sort results where the term appears in both first, then ones where it appears only in the title, then ones where it appears only in the text.

**A couple of notes of caution:**

1. This is a *very naive* interpretation - what happens if your search term is `top hats and tails` - do you only want to match that exact phrase? Should you be split it up and then assign a score per word? If you do that, do you want to return results where the title or text contains `and` as a search result? How do you weight them? If one word matches multiple times should that score as highly as different words matching once each?
2. This is a fairly common problem and in the Ruby world that means that *someone has probably solved it already* in fact there are probably many people who have solved it. It is always worth searching around to see whether there are any convenient gems you can drop into your bundle that will allow you to use someone else's code to solve your problems - in this case something like [SearchLogic](https://github.com/railsdog/searchlogic) looks as though it could help.

Comment: Its really awesome way, you make me to think in different way,
i accepted your answer, but i were thinking to solve this problem via positioning query by PostgreSQL which returns integer, i were thinking to count the title search result and then ordering...
have you experience about that ?
BTW lot of thanks for your brilliant approach.

Comment: You can perform the same logic in SQL working in Postgres to generate a score in a similar way. You might also look for full-text search options that it offers ( I haven't used this much with PgSQL ) which could do most of the job for you. Before going too far in that direction, think about the difficulties of database vs application management- it will be easier to write and to deploy if written in the application layer and it won't put business logic into the database. So yes, you can do it and probably the database can help you, but it may not be the best option.

Comment: hey @glenatron, what do you think about query within query?

Comment: It moves some of the work into SQL which is of mixed benefit ( unless you really know for certain that you are definitely going to run into performance issues outside SQL then you probably don't want to be doing too much in the database for the reasons in my comment above- it's almost always a premature optimisation ) but to be honest if I was going to chuck that much code in the database might as well use a stored procedure or similar. Better to have logic in the business layer than the data layer, when you can.